# How to create configuration files based on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I manipulate params in a more DSL way per country where each country has its own logic for province variable.

I would like to organise it better:
- create a configuration file per per each country.
- if files not exist than there will be a default file
- and each file is a ruby file that province parameter can be manipulated via ruby code which gives flexibility.

currently I do it in in the controller like this:

```
before_filter :modify_location_params, :only => [:create]

def location_params
  params.require(:location).permit(
    origin:               [:name, :country, :city, :state, :postal_code, :address1, :address2,:province],
    destination:          [:name, :country, :city, :state, :postal_code, :address1, :address2,:province],
  )
end


def modify_location_params
  [:origin, :destination].each do |location|
    unless (params[:location][location][:country].downcase =~ /(Sweden|sw)/).nil?

      params[:location][location][:province] = 'SW'
    end
    unless (params[:location][location][:country].downcase == 'IL' && some_other_condition == true 

      params[:location][location][:city] = 'OM'
      params[:location][location][:name] = 'some name'
    end
  end
end
```

Yes, I can do it in a switch/if statements but I think that since I have a lot of countries it would be a better way of doing a DSL like system for this manipulating. any ideas how implement such?

Comment: https://simpleror.wordpress.com/2014/11/19/configuration-pattern-in-ruby/

Comment: Why not a database? Or a YAML file?

Comment: I would like to manipulate the params of the controller in a very different way per location and YML not flexible enough for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not totally sure I understand what you're trying to do, but if you just want different implementations of a similar method for each country you could make a class for each one and have them inherit from a parent country class. Something like

```
class Country
  def as_origin
    #default code
  end
end

class Sweden < Country
  def as_origin
    #override default code here
  end
end
```

There's also a bunch of good gems to help with [country information](https://github.com/hexorx/countries) if you want to avoid doing it all by hand

Comment: Well, I thought of something more like DSL that will gives me the flexibility. I made a few changes to the question so now instead of manipulating params in model I do it in the controller. what do you think?

Comment: I don't know enough about domain specific languages to say for sure but this doesn't sound complicated enough to need it. As for changing your params I've always been taught to have fat models and skinny controllers. You probably want to abstract as much logic to your models as you can because controller actions can get bloated pretty quickly

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to add different key-value pairs to a hash depending on the `:country` value in that hash.  If so then a YAML file should work.

Say you have the following in a YAML file

```
# country_details.yaml
sweden:
    province: 'SW'
il:
    city: 'OM'
    name: 'some name'
```

Then you can define a method

```
def country_details(country)
  parsed_yaml = YAML::load(File.open('path/to/file'))
  details = parsed_yaml[country]
end
```

that you use like so

```
details = country_details('SW')
params[:location][location].merge! details
```